# Problems with Defining exports

Tags: visual-c++, warnings, c-preprocessor

I am trying to build a Dynamic DLL in VC++ 2008, now in a .h file, I declare the following

```
#ifndef  PREFILTER_LIBRARY_H
#define  PREFILTER_LIBRARY_H

#ifdef PREFILTER_EXPORTS
#   define PREFILTER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define PREFILTER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#endif
```

While in the PreFilter.h file I am writing

```
class PREFILTER_API  PreFilter
{
...
};
```

The problem is I keep getting:

```
warning C4273: 'PreFilter::Apply' : inconsistent dll linkage
```

I  see that the dllexport part of the above macros is not highlighted and is commented which should have been the other way around, plus I have another .h file that contains Apply() method.

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to export the functions of PreFilter.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add PREFILTER_EXPORTS to the list of preprocessor constants in Dll project settings: Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - C++ - Preprocessor - Preprocessor definitions.

When this file is used in Dll project, PREFILTER_EXPORTS is defined in the project, and PREFILTER_API is expanded as __declspec(dllexport). In any other project, where PREFILTER_EXPORTS is not defined, PREFILTER_API is expanded as __declspec(dllimport).

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked like a charm!